# Persistindo times de projetos

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, orm

Em um sistema de gerenciamento de projetos temos as entidades "Usuários" e "Projetos".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de evoluir essa estrutura básica para uma estrutura que comportasse times. Exemplo: O Projeto 1 tem 3 integrantes.

Qual a melhor forma de persistir essa estrutura ? Seria essa ? Onde um usuário criaria o projeto e depois poderia adicionar novos membros a estrutura...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse modelo me parece bom. é simples, se pensar que Usuarios - Projetos é uma relação `n:n` ou `n:m`, basicamente um tabela de ligação como a Usuarios_Projetos resolve

Answer (score 0):

Somente crie a entidade `Papel` e na entidade `Usuarios_Projetos` substitua o campo `Papel` por `papel_id`.

Remova a coluna `Usuarios_id` da entidade `Projetos`.

Como boa prática, recomendo deixar o nome das colunas em minúsculo.